# How to clear HttpURLConnection's cache in Android?

Tags: java, android, json, caching, httpurlconnection

I have an application which sends a GET request to a link and get some JSON data back from the server, then saves them in a List of Posts (a custom Java object) and show the result in activity...

The problem is, it shows me the cached result! So if I change something in that JSON file, it takes a while for my application to show those changes!

I'm using `HttpURLConnection` for connecting to the server, and I also tried using `.setUseCaches`:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            
connection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
...
...
```

But it didn't work either...

What should I do?

#### EDIT (I forgot to mention):

After I change that value and open the JSON file in PC's browser (any browser), I see the new result, not the cached one... But Android uses the cached version!

Comment: It doesn't have a cache. The intermediate servers and proxies have caches. You usually have to address this problem at the server end.

Comment: @EJP No, it's not the server! I forgot to mention this: After I change that value and open the JSON file in PC's browser (any browser), I see the new result, not the cached one... But Android uses the cached version!

Comment: I didn't say it was the server. Read my comment again.

Comment: @EJP Sorry, I misunderstood then... Would you please explain more about it?

Comment: @MR.Garcia Did you found the answer. I faced to the same issue also

Comment: @Paul No, I wrote my own PHP codes from scratch!

Comment: @MR.Garcia. I have found a solution that sets the cache-control property for the request header. It is: connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache"). In my case, that code works as expected

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the solution, but that didn't work for me!

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
    //create connect http
    URL oURL = new java.net.URL("http://some.site.url");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) oURL.openConnection();

    // set none cache
    con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    con.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer here, although I let go of the code and used my own way, but it wasn't the problem, I already had `no-cache` and `no-store` in my code